# Listbox Selected Item is always null after an update in the list box in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, listbox

In my WPF application I have a list box which have list of quiz match am playing. Each time a match is created by me / any other opponent am reloading the list.

Current Scenario: Am playing a match, my current match is highlighted based on its ID. While playing itself some other person sends me an invite and it automatically refreshes the list and selected Item turns null. It affects the match which am currently playing.

I need the selectedItem to be same unless the user clicks on other match. So I maintain the ID in the variable and even after reloading the list , with that old ID I want that item to be selected.

```
List<ChallengePlayerLists> ChallengerLists;
var filteredlistfortest2 = ChallengerList.Where(x => x.challengeID == Convert.ToString(challengeID) && (x.challengeStatus == "Your turn")).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
                lstChallengeGrid.SelectedItem =  ChallengerList.Where(x => x.challengeID == Convert.ToString(challengeID) && (x.challengeStatus == "Your turn")).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

public class ChallengePlayerLists
{ 
    public string challengeID { get; set; }
    public string challengeType { get; set; }
    public string challengerID { get; set; }
    public string opponentID { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string challengeStatus { get; set; }
}
```

First line of code works as expected, I can get the match I want to be selected using the LINQ query. But while assigning it to `listbox.SelectedItem` it remains as  NULL.

I am not sure why it is null while assigning the same LINQ  to `selectedItem`.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but why do you have `.ToList().FirstOrDefault()`? You can simple have `.FirstOrDefault()` at the end.

Comment: @Bas there is a lot of why ? Like why the ID column is string, why not directly call ChanllengerList.FirstOrDefault. If your result is null probably there is no item which met your where conditions.

Comment: also, are you sure checking the challangeStatus is correct here? What happens if its not "Your turn"?

Comment: Can you post the code of the object which populates your list? the one with the `challengeID` property.

Comment: @mybirthname ID i have converted to string so that I can compare the value with my List. List is returned from Web API in which the ID is returned as string. If the conditions or not met it must not return to the filteredlistfortest2 variable. It returns there correctly.

Comment: @vkluge - yes challengeStatus is correct , if it is not Your Turn then that challenge must not be selected in the list

Comment: @Bas - I replaced .ToList.FirstOrDefault() to .FirstOrDefault(). it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are changing the list bound to the ListBox then this will make the `SelectedItem` invalid. You will need to store a way of finding the currently selected item - it's Id or a unique code and then reselect it once the list has been updated:

```
int selectedItemId = SelectedItem.Id;
ChallengerLists = updatedList;
SelectedItem = ChallengerLists.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == selectedItemId);
```